# At what age may a student log time and use that time to obtain a rating?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training, logging, student-pilot

A few years back the FAA was upset about young pilots attempting to set records and crashing in the process.

Were there any rules instituted regarding logging of time with a CFI / instructor? May a 9 year old or 12 year old log time flown with a CFI and use that time to qualify for a rating?

Comment: Hello Zeus, welcome to [Aviation.SE](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/). Which jurisdiction are you interested to hear the answers for, as this may vary from country to country?

Comment: FAA rules in USA.

Comment: I did not look into regs yet, but I know of kids that take lessons at that age (which sure isn't illegal) and log those so they can do their first solo (which requires a minimum age) ASAP. this goes for many countries btw,in Germany you can fly gliders solo with 14, but you need to be 16 to get your license...

Comment: More than just the FAA - after the death of 7 year old Jessica Dubroff (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jessica_Dubroff), Clinton introduced the Child Pilot Safety act, prohibiting anybody from attempting aviation records without already holding a licence and medical.

Comment: I know a CFI friend, who's 4 year old holds 10 hrs dual in his logbook.

Answer (score 10):

FAR [§ 61.83](http://www.flightsimaviation.com/data/FARS/part_61-83.html) states:

> To be eligible for a student pilot certificate, an applicant must:
>
> (a) Be at least 16 years of age for other than the operation of a glider or balloon.
>
> (b) Be at least 14 years of age for the operation of a glider or balloon.
>
> (c) Be able to read, speak, write, and understand the English language. [...]

A **student pilot certificate** enables you to fly a plane solo or on a solo cross country.
In other words, you need to be at least 16 years old to fly a plane (non glider/balloon) solo.

[image: This is an example of a student pilot certificate. It comes with your medical usually.]

Now, back to your initial question. If you go through FAR [§61.83 - §61.95](http://www.flightsimaviation.com/data/FARS/part_61.html) you will find all the regulations about student pilots (which would be the kind of pilot you are referring to ).

I have found **no age restriction** going through them for the pre-solo instruction. All it says that it must be done before soloing which does require a medical exam and certificate ([but these don't have age restrictions either](https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/medical_certification/faq/response7/)).

**Summing up, a 9 or 12 year old child is legally able to take flying lessons with an instructor, but may not solo before his/her 16th birthday (no glider/balloons).**

Comment: You might want to clarify what "you must have a medical before starting your training" means. It conflicts with your statement that there's no age restriction for pre-solo training.

Comment: I knew someone who logged time before they were 16 but soloed and got their license after their birthday. I can confirm that this will "fly" with the FAA.